# first line in contentEditable div is not tagged

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

```js
$('#btnsave').click(function(){
console.log($('#story').html());
});
```

```css
#story{
background:gold;
min-height:54px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='story' contentEditable='true'></div>
<br>
<button id='btnsave'>SAVE</button>
```

if `story` has a single line content, for example `lorem ipsum` console.log gives `lorem ipsum`.

Each of NEXT lines are wrapped with `<div></div>` tags.

Why the first line is not tagged and how to get this functionality?

Comment: The first line isn't tagged probably so that you won't get any extraneous tags when there's only one line.

Comment: @Barmar, hmm... that should not be `extraneous ` but normal tags for a line, regardless it is on start, middle or on end of input.

Comment: The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#contenteditable) doesn't provide any guidance on what the result of this should be. I guess it can return any HTML that would be rendered as what the user typed, and there doesn't seem to be any way to control it.